# Using byobu on KVM Guest via Serial Console

Tags: kvm-virtualization, byobu

I am logged in to a KVM Guest (running Ubuntu 12.04 on Centos 6.6 host).  I followed the instructions here [Access pty login prompt in VM](https://serverfault.com/questions/632718/access-pty-login-prompt-in-vm)

The problem is that the console fills the terminal window just fine when I connect with "virsh console " but if I try to open byobu, screens, or vim, I can only use an 80x24 window.  I tried using "screen" and "screen-bce" instead of "xterm" in the ttyS0.conf file, as well as changing the TERM variable in my console and screens/byobu, but no combination seems to let me utilize my entire window.

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The virtual console you're using is a virtualized serial port. It has absolutely no idea -- and no way of knowing -- how large the virtual terminal really is. So, you have to give it this information explicitly with `stty`.

For instance:

```
stty rows 24 columns 80
```

Or you can use a virtual PC console instead of a virtual serial port, but you may need to reconfigure the virtual machine to do that.